# Range(...).Value = vbNullString is true when Value is the number 0?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to check if some cells in  excel are empty. So I do a comparison with vbNullString, which worked fine. But now, it seems as if the comparison is true when the cells contain the number zero? How can this be?

Thanks for advices,
Florian

Comment: If you want to test a cell for emptiness, use `IsEmpty()`. Don't compare it to `vbNullString`.

Comment: If you have 0 entered into the cell, then `vbNullString` wont be returning true.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because if the cell contains the number zero, then **it's not empty**.

The `.Value` property of a `Range` object in Excel is not typed *if nothing is written yet*. In other words, when the cell contains nothing, it's comparable with both string and numeric "empty" values:

```
Empty cell value = vbNullString --> True
```

because literally talking its value is `""`

```
Empty cell value = 0 --> True
```

because numerically talking its value is `0`

...and this happen because you still didn't type the value of that range object, so at run time the cell is still considered as containing a `Variant` type (which means that the type is not defined, so it's like a zero if that was numerical and like an empty string if that was a string).

However, when you type `0` (or this is the output of a formula, such as `=2-2`), you're assigning the type "Numeric" to that range. The cell becomes *Numeric* Which means:

*Is the numerical null type (`0`) equal to a null string? `False`*

*Is the numerical null type (`0`) equal to zero? `True`*

If you want zero to be considered as the `Null` alternative to the string `""` (i.e. the constant `vbNullString`), then you should enrich your condition with the numerical check `.Value = 0`.

Comment: `vbNullString` is not the same as a zero length string (`""`). `vbNullString` is a string having the value `0`. A zero-length string takes up storage (a BSTR header, essentially). `vbNullString` is essentially just a null string pointer.

Comment: I tried to change the format of the cells that are worked on to e.g. '0.00' and I tried to rearrange the NumberFormat Property of the Range-Object. Both brought no success, when I try to use IsEmpty() or the comparison with vbNullString the cell is detected empty. This is because the Range.Value is empty even when there is 0.00 in the cell. What to do? :(